# remove extra length from string converted from array in rust

Tags: arrays, string, asynchronous, rust

I am trying to learn async in rust with tokio. I am trying to take input from the terminal by using  [tokio::io::AsyncReadExt::Read](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read) which need array as buffer. But when I convert that buffer into a string, I can't compare it with other strings cause I think it has extra length.

here is minimal code:-

```
use std::process::Command;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::time;

async fn get_input(prompt: &str) -> String {
    println!("{}", prompt);

    let mut f = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];

    // read up to 10 bytes
    f.read(&mut buffer).await;

    String::from_utf8((&buffer).to_vec()).unwrap()
}

async fn lol() {
    for i in 1..5 {
        let mut input = get_input("lol asks ").await;
        input.shrink_to_fit();
        print!("lol {} input = '{}' len = {}", i, input, input.len());

        if input.eq("sl\n") {
            let mut konsole = Command::new("/usr/bin/konsole");
            konsole.arg("-e").arg("sl");
            konsole.output().expect("some error happend");
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let h = lol();

    futures::join!(h);
}
```

if I execute this code, I get this:-

```
lol asks 
sl
lol 1 input = 'sl
' len = 10lol asks
```

which means string has 10 length

Answer (score 0):

I solved with help from Discord people

I needed to use the number returned by f.read(…).await.unwrap(), otherwise, you will have some additional zero bytes at the end which were not returned by reading

```
let i = f.read(&mut buffer).await.unwrap() ;

String::from_utf8((&buffer[..i]).to_vec()).unwrap()
```